# Creating Let's ecrypt SSL for my Kuberenetes service using Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, lets-encrypt, cert-manager, istio-gateway

Hope you are doing well. I have a domain `onlinetransport.africa` I want SSL for the domain so I decided to use the Let’s encrypt. I wrote some script which is:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: onlinetransport-domain-cert-prod
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  secretName: onlinetransport-domain-cert-prod
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod-cluster
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: onlinetransport.africa
  dnsNames:
    - "www.onlinetransport.africa"
    - "onlinetransport.africa"

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: landing-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - "www.onlinetransport.africa"
    - "onlinetransport.africa"
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: onlinetransport-domain-cert-prod
  - hosts:
    - "www.onlinetransport.africa"
    - "onlinetransport.africa"
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: landing-page-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
    - 'onlinetransport.africa'
    - 'www.onlinetransport.africa'
  gateways:
    - istio-system/landing-ingressgateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: ot-landing-page-svc.ot-landing-page-ns.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
    retries:
      attempts: 10
      perTryTimeout: 60s
```

The certificate was created, and an ssl was attached with the gateway. so far so good.
But then I feel I need some subdomains like. `console.onlinetransport.africa` and `api.onlinetransport.africa` and some other, So I decided to wrote some more script to issue a certificate for that as well, the other code is look like;

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: console-ingress-cert
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  secretName: console-onlinetransport-domain-cert-prod
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod-cluster
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: 'console.onlinetransport.africa'
  dnsNames:
    - "console.onlinetransport.africa"

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: console-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - "console.onlinetransport.africa"
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: console-onlinetransport-domain-cert-prod
  - hosts:
    - "console.onlinetransport.africa"
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: console-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
    - 'console.onlinetransport.africa'
  gateways:
    - console-ingressgateway
  http:
  - name: user-dashboard
    match:
    - uri: 
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: ot-user-dashboard-svc.ot-user-dashboard-ns.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
    retries:
      attempts: 10
      perTryTimeout: 60s
```

This will not create the certificate, when I look with the cert-manager logs it says.

```
E0225 09:37:21.038944       1 sync.go:190] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="failed to perform self check GET request 'http://console.onlinetransport.africa/.well-known/acme-challenge/roHJLg4TtiHjgkQumMue4CaCNMP3IgReoramujphJRE': Get \"https://console.onlinetransport.africa/.well-known/acme-challenge/roHJLg4TtiHjgkQumMue4CaCNMP3IgReoramujphJRE\": read tcp 10.244.2.58:48906->159.65.214.235:443: read: connection reset by peer" "dnsName"="console.onlinetransport.africa" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="console-ingress-cert-6dzv2-1153112560-3888303437" "resource_namespace"="istio-system" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
```

Here is my cluster issuer.

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod-cluster
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory  
    email: info@onlinetransport.com 
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod-cluster
    solvers:
      - selector: {}
        http01:
          ingress:
            class: istio
```

Any help or suggestion are appreciated :)

Let me know If you need futher details and logs.

Comment: What does 'kubectl get ingressclas -n istio-system' return? I also suggest you use ingress-shim to automatically create certificates whenever an ingress is made available. It is a sub-component of cert-manager and is added through the annotation `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod-cluster` on your ingress. Also cluster-issuers aren't limited to a namespace so you can remove it from your YAML.

Comment: I am not using the default kubernetes ingress. instead I am istio. So in case of istio we need to create a certificate by your self.